# Javascript object model

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several questions about how Javascript object work.

I understood that Javascript work by inheritance. But there are things that I not able to understand

First, when we digging through some objects in javascript, It happens that we found not all object property. But when we create our own objects, the debug show everything.

For example, a Bootstrap Dropdown object will show this :

```
$(".dropdown").dropdown()
(9) [li.dropdown.active, li.dropdown.test, a#addConsumption.dropdown.toggle, li.dropdown.dropdown-accordion, a#addConsumption.dropdown.toggle, li.dropdown, a#addTemperature.dropdown.toggle, li.dropdown, a#addPresence.dropdown.toggle, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]

$(".dropdown").data("bs.dropdown")
Dropdown {}__proto__: Object
```

When a MyObject object will output the following :

```
DropdownAccordion {accordions: Array(0), component: r.fn.init(1), dropdown_menu: r.fn.init(1), menu_panel_group: r.fn.init(1)}
```

property1
:
[]
property2
:
[div.panel-group, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
**proto**
:
Object

So **how do this work ?**

And, for example in Bootstrap, **how DOM with class like ".dropdown" are instantiated**? In fact, I dug through the dropdown.js and tried to find when instantiation occurs, but it never happens. So maybe there is another concept of Javascript instantiation that I don't know existed.

```
// This section appear to never happen, unless we instantiate like "$(selector).dropdown()
function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array that gets printed out to the console is a HTMLCollection (or a jQuery Collection), basically a list of HTMLElements. When you put them out in the console, your browser will format the output differently, such that when you hover above the output elements, they will also be marked in the DOM, as if you would inspect them. However, you can still get the prototype methods of the class with `$(".dropdown").__proto__` for example.

Regarding your second question: Usually these elements, which produce new html elements in the DOM, get rendered from javascript, so you should find something in the code, maybe not in the dropdown.js.